# Freeze div at top of Masterpage

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

How do I freeze the top section of a MasterPage so that the menu doesn't scroll off the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support more browsers, you can also look at the [AlwaysVisibleControl](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AlwaysVisibleControl/AlwaysVisibleControl.aspx)  which comes with the free ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit

Comment: I tried it and it's cool, but theres sort of a delayed effect where it catches up.  I was hoping for something similar to the bar at the top of this page that tells me I have 1 new answer.

Comment: The delay is because in older browsers, it's using Javascript to handle the scroll event.  You will not see the delay in newer browsers, so those users will have a slightly better experience.  If you see a bar on this page, you could view source, or use firebug to find out how SO is doing it ;-)

Answer (score 6):

[CSS Fixed Header Layout](http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/header)

Answer (score 1):

You can used the position:fixed css style, but this only works with modern browsers (FF3, IE7).  If you want to support older browsers you have to get more creative, using Javascript and such.

Comment: yeah we have old browsers here - ie6